# How do I set up a Dell C1760 printer?

Tags: 14.04, printing

New to ubuntu. Have DOS and windows experience
I am trying to install a Dell C1760 printer on Ubuntu 14.04 without success. Can anyone give me a step by step answer?
Thanks in advance